# nvd3 Line Chart on Meteor JS: 'addGraph' Error

Tags: javascript, meteor, nvd3.js

Using the official nvd3 package (https://atmospherejs.com/nvd3/nvd3)

I have the following code under the Template.rendered block:

```
var formattedEarnedData = formatEarnedData(userEarnedDataSet);

nv.addGraph(function() {
    var earnedChart = nv.models.lineChart()
        .margin({ left: 25 })
        .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
        .transition()
        .duration(350)
        .showLegend(true)
        .showYAxis(true)
        .showXAxis(true);

    earnedChart.xAxis
        .axisLabel('Date')
        .tickFormat(d3.format('d'));

    earnedChart.yAxis
        .axisLabel('Earned')
        .tickFormat(d3.format('d'));

    d3.select('#earned-charts svg').datum(
        [{
            key: 'Earned',
            values: formattedEarnedData
        }]
    ).call(earnedChart);

    nv.utils.windowResize(earnedChart.update);

    return earnedChart;
});
```

The following lies at the bottom of the js file outside of the rendered block:

```
var formatEarnedData = function(dataSet) {
    var earnedDataArray = new Array();
    var groupedDates = _.groupBy(_.pluck(dataSet, 'progression'), function(date) {
    return moment(date).format('MMM D');
});

_.each(_.values(groupedDates), function(dates) {
    earnedDataArray.push({
        date: dates[0],
        total: dates.length
    });
});

return earnedDataArray;
}
```

Even after following the documentation, I am still getting this error:

```
Cannot read property 'addGraph' of undefined
```

Can any nvd3 experts shed some light on why this error is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverting back to 1.1.0.2 wasn't needed, all you need to do is revert the nvd3 package to 1.7.1. See here:

https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/1185

Answer (score 0):

You need to revert back meteor version Meteor 1.1.0.2 .Work charm!

Comment: 1.2 came out a few day ago. do you mean 1.1.0.2?

Comment: just tried this and it's the same error 'addGraph' isn't defined

Comment: if that example functioning, that your code need to refactor

Comment: you also can refers this link for more details: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245

Comment: yes, we've been mimicking these examples and it's showing that addGraph error still

Comment: have you tried debug using inspect element on console ?